# Can Azure Backup Server backup databases participating in Log Shipping?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, azure

We have a number of log-shipped SQL 2017 databases which we wish to start backing up using Microsoft Azure Backup Server (locally and to the cloud) on a 15 minute schedule.

Does anyone know if it is possible for Azure Backup Server to hook into the log backups made by SQL Server log shipping?

Comment: As per [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup) it says `With Azure Backup Server, you can protect application workloads such as Hyper-V VMs, *Microsoft SQL Server*, SharePoint Server, Microsoft Exchange, and Windows clients from a single console.` So it believe it can, since I have not tried yet so not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

azbackup add-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>"
azbackup modify-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>" -backupinterval 15
azbackup modify-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>" -retentionperiod 7
```

1. `azbackup add-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>"`: This command adds a SQL instance to the backup configuration. Replace `<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>` with the actual name of your SQL instance.
2. `azbackup modify-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>" -backupinterval 15`: This command modifies the backup interval for the specified SQL instance. The `-backupinterval` parameter sets the interval (in minutes) between backups. In this example, it is set to 15 minutes.
3. `azbackup modify-sqlinstance -instancename "<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>" -retentionperiod 7`: This command modifies the retention period for the specified SQL instance. The `-retentionperiod` parameter sets the number of days to retain the backups. In this example, it is set to 7 days.

Comment: Please explain what it means